# How do i change the bgcolor in a custom view? Obj-c xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

i am making a cocoa application for a mac.

I'm pretty new to xcodes IB so i might have missed a few things.

Basically i am making an app with multiple views for menubar buttons and stuff like that. I would like to show and hide content view from a press of buttons.

My problem is:
I cant change the properties for my different custom views. there seem to be no properties to change like the backgroundcolor. What have i missed?

Xcode 5.0 - Std. Cocoa application

Comment: Objective-C **xor** Xcode? I. e. do you want to change the color programmatically or from within Interface Builder? Those two are completely unrelated things.

Comment: you cant set a background color for NSView directly... you can override `-(void)drawRect` method.

Comment: I just want to apply background color and make bordors around my views . I dont need to change it upon runtime.

When i am looking at the attributes inspector there is not shown anything? - my best reference is like the properties for a grid in Visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom class of your view and implement below:-

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
 [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
     NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
     [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    }
```

Comment: Let me get this right.

I need to create a new class whitch enherits from NSView and then paste the drawRect function in the .m file. - Correct?

And then i can use the new View class in my interface builder?

Am i totally wrong?

Comment: Holy Moly! I got it! thank you so much! i have spent way to much time on this!